# Prolog sorting lists by position

Tags: list, prolog

I'm very new to Prolog and I'm trying to go through a list and check that each element is in the right spot of the list. for example, say you have a list of colours and each color is assigned a numerical value of 0 or 1. I want to check that all even positions in the list have the value of 0 and odd positions have a value of 1 (begin list at 0 being even).

```
red = 0
blue = 1
yellow = 0
orange = 1
green = 1
list1 = [red, blue, yellow, orange]
list2 = [red, yellow, orange, blue]
```

so basically in the example above, I'd like list 1 to come back true as its values go [0,1,0,1] and list2 to come back false as its values are [0,0,1,1]

Comment: Is this a homework? Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any programming language, you must follow its syntax rules. Your code seems Javascript, not Prolog. Could be instead

```
color(red, 0).
color(blue, 1).
...
colors(list1, [red, blue, yellow, orange]).
...
```

Once completed, we can write

```
check_colors(List) :-
  colors(List, Cs),
  forall(nth0(I, Cs, C), (N is I mod 2, color(C, N))).
```

You most likely need to replace forall/2 with your own 'list visit'. Start with I = 0

```
check_colors(List) :-
  colors(List, Cs),
  check_colors(Cs, 0).
```

and increment it before the recursive call. The recursion will complete (implicitly resulting in `true`) on empty list

```
check_colors([], _).
```

Please try to write the rest of the procedure...

Comment: ok I've written most of it. As someone asked above, yesh this is a homework question. Found out i have to do it by only doing relations. So i have 2 mutual recursive statements that work well in taking the head, checking value then sending it to the next relation. My only problem now is when I have an empty list left it does something weird (used trace). how do i make it stop at the empty list?

Comment: why `2 mutual recursive statements` ? Should only 1 direct recursive clause `check_colors([C|Cs], I) :- ... `, and this will stop at the base case I've shown

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way it comes to my mind is the following:

```
color(red,0).
color(blue,1).
color(yellow,0).
color(orange,1).
color(green,1).

%base cases.    
colors([X]):-color(X,_).
colors([]).

colors([X,Y|Xs]):-
    color(X,Cx), %X is a color with Cx ( 0 or 1)
    color(Y,Cy), %Y is a color with Cy ( 0 or 1)
    \+member(X,[Y|Xs]), % X is not  in the list
    Cx=\=Cy, % they are different
    colors([Y|Xs]). % continue recursion.
```